# Return the maximum amount by designation code

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, max

I have the following script:

```
SELECT DESG_ID, 
       DESG_CODE, 
       MAX(DESG_AMOUNT)
  FROM DESG_TABLE   
  GROUP BY DESG_ID, 
           DESG_CODE
```

It will return the following:

```
DESG_ID  DESG_CODE       DESG_AMOUNT
1        A               $100
1        B               $50
1        C               $300
2        A               $60
2        B               $25
2        C               $10
```

How do I get it to return only the maximum value and display just that row?

```
DESG_ID      DESG_CODE       DESG_AMOUNT
1            C               $300
2            A               $60
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way should work:

```
with base_qry as
(SELECT DESG_ID, 
       DESG_CODE, 
       DESG_AMOUNT,
       MAX(DESG_AMOUNT) over (partition by DESG_ID) as MAX_DESG_AMT
  FROM DESG_TABLE )

select DESG_ID,
      DESG_CODE,
      DESG_AMOUNT
from base_qry
where DESG_AMT = MAX_DESG_AMT
```

Use the analytics function (max . . . over . . . partition by) to append the appropriate maximum onto each row, then take only the rows where the amount = the maximum.

This will return 1 row per ID, unless there are ties in your data - if your data looked like this:

```
DESG_ID  DESG_CODE       DESG_AMOUNT
1        A               $300
1        B               $50
1        C               $300
```

Would return:

```
DESG_ID  DESG_CODE       DESG_AMOUNT
    1        A               $300
    1        C               $300
```

Since you've got 2 rows that match the maximum. If you want only 1 row per DESG_ID, then you can use row_number instead of max in the query like:

```
with base_qry as
(SELECT DESG_ID, 
       DESG_CODE, 
       DESG_AMOUNT,
       row_number over (partition by DESG_ID order by DESG_AMT desc)
           as row_num
  FROM DESG_TABLE )

select DESG_ID,
      DESG_CODE,
      DESG_AMOUNT
from base_qry
where row_num = 1
```

One thing I think I should mention - the other answers are correct ways to do what you originally asked. They were posted before the question was edited to remove "where DESG_ID = '1'". That is a significant change.

Comment: Hi Dandarc, I meant for more than one ID, so you are and the other posters are correct in that respect. 

When I run your script, I get an ORA-00904 (invalid identifier) error. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Thank you for the in-depth reply.

Comment: Had an extra parenthesis - sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT DESG_ID, DESG_CODE, MAX(DESG_AMOUNT) as AMT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DESG_AMOUNT) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM DESG_TABLE
      WHERE DESG_ID = '1'
      GROUP BY DESG_ID, DESG_CODE
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You can change `ROW_NUMBER()` to `RANK()` if you want multiple rows when there are ties.

Actually, you are using `MAX()`.  You don't need the `GROUP BY`.  So how about:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT DESG_ID, DESG_CODE, DESG_AMOUNT
      FROM DESG_TABLE
      WHERE DESG_ID = '1'
      ORDER BY DESG_AMOUNT DESC
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Or in Oracle 12+:

```
SELECT DESG_ID, DESG_CODE, DESG_AMOUNT
FROM DESG_TABLE
WHERE DESG_ID = '1'
ORDER BY DESG_AMOUNT DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

EDIT:

If you want one code per `id` (which was not clear when I first read the question), then:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT DESG_ID, DESG_CODE, DESG_AMOUNT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DESG_AMOUNT) DESC as seqnum
      FROM DESG_TABLE
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the from loop works when there is one id, since it'll return only one row. But it will not for multiple ids. The desire is to get one row returned for each id. Thank you again for responsing.

Answer (score 0):

How about below query to retrive highest in each group

```
select a.*
from DESG_TABLE a
join(
select distinct DESG_ID, max(DESG_AMOUNT) over(partition by DESG_ID order by DESG_AMOUNT desc) DESG_AMOUNT
from DESG_TABLE ) b 
on a.DESG_ID=b.DESG_ID 
and a.DESG_AMOUNT=b.DESG_AMOUNT
```

if DESG_AMOUNT is varchar since i see $ append , below query will work

```
select a.*
from DESG_TABLE a
join(
select distinct DESG_ID, '$'||max(to_number(substr(DESG_AMOUNT,2))) over(partition by DESG_ID order by to_number(substr(DESG_AMOUNT,2)) desc ) DESG_AMOUNT
from DESG_TABLE) b
on a.DESG_ID=b.DESG_ID 
and a.DESG_AMOUNT=b.DESG_AMOUNT
```

Final query to include all 3 columns in join without distinct operation

```
select a.*
from DESG_TABLE a
join(
select  DESG_ID,DESG_CODE, '$'||max(to_number(substr(DESG_AMOUNT,2))) over(partition by DESG_ID order by to_number(substr(DESG_AMOUNT,2)) desc ) DESG_AMOUNT
from DESG_TABLE) b
on a.DESG_ID=b.DESG_ID 
and a.DESG_CODE=b.DESG_CODE 
and a.DESG_AMOUNT=b.DESG_AMOUNT
```

Comment: Hi Kanagaraj, your script worked as well. Thank you for replying.